# html5-video download progress only working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have the following function to calculate the loading progress of a video (quite common):

```
function updateProgressBar (video) {
   if (video.buffered.length > 0) {
       var percent = (video.buffered.end(0) / video.duration) * 100;
       $('#loading').css({'width': percent + '%'});
       console.log(percent);
       if (percent == 100) {
           console.log('video loaded!');
           //everything is loaded, do something.
           $(video).unbind('loadeddata canplaythrough playing'); //prevents the repetition of the callback
       }
   }        
}
```

...bound to the 'progress' event (and some others as a safety meassure) inside a $(document).ready function:

```
var videoTest = document.getElementById("videoTest");

$('#videoTest').bind('progress', function () {
     updateProgressBar (videoTest);
});

$('#videoTest').bind('loadeddata', function () {
     updateProgressBar (videoTest);
});

$('#videoTest').bind('canplaythrough', function () {
     updateProgressBar (videoTest);
});

$('#videoTest').bind('playing', function () {
     updateProgressBar (videoTest);
});
```

**You can view a live example here:** http://www.hidden-workshop.com/video/

As you can see, it all works well on firefox, but in the rest of the browsers, the 'percent' variable never reaches the value of '100' as it would be expected; the function always stops at 90~, and thus I'm unable to know when the video has finished loading (vital for what I'm trying to do).

It's like the 'progress' event stops working before I can get the final value of 'percent', because if you click the 'play' button, the 'playing' event fires and then successfully calculates and reads the 'percent' variable's last value (which is 100).

Am I missing something, or is it a common issue? Is there any workaround I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
var videoElement = null; //TODO set reference to video element

var checkVideoLoadingProgressTimerDelay = 50;
var checkVideoLoadingProgressTimerID = -1;

function getVideoLoadingProgress(){
    var end = 0;
    if(videoElement.buffered.length >= 1){
        end = videoElement.buffered.end(0);
    }
    var progress = end / videoElement.duration;
    progress = isNaN(progress) ? 0 : progress;
    return progress;
};

function startCheckVideoLoadingProgressTimer(){
    checkVideoLoadingProgressTimerID = 
        setTimeout(checkVideoLoadingProgressTimerHandler, checkVideoLoadingProgressTimerDelay);
};

function checkVideoLoadingProgressTimerHandler(){
    var progress = getVideoLoadingProgress();
    //TODO update progress bar
    if(progress < 1){
        startCheckVideoLoadingProgressTimer();
    }
};
```

Also value "auto" for "preload" attribute of video not guarantee that user agent will load whole video.